# C++ Boost and ImageMagick++ API issue

Tags: c++, boost, imagemagick

While developing Raspberry Pi library compiled by g++4.9.2 I have met compability issue between boost (1.6.2) and ImageMagick++ API (7.0). When compiling this code:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
```

I got these boost errors:

```
__assert_fail was not declared in this scope (path_trails.hpp)
...
__assert_fail was not declared in this scope (path.hpp)
...
__assert_fail was not declared in this scope (shared_ptr.hpp)
```

When deleting `#include <Magick++.h>` line everything runs fine. Unfortunately I need boost and ImageMagick as well in this source file. How to solve this issue?

Comment: The library used reserved identifiers (double underscore) and is now reaping the consequence, it looks like. Which is a bit weird if it's actually in boost. What compiler, toolchain and versions?

Comment: Might need to updated boost to the latest version. I'm not seeing such issues when compiling with clang.

Answer (score 4):

A simple workaround is to include Magick++.h after boost.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <Magick++.h>
```

I don't have a proper explanation for this problem but it seems to come from a clash when using different headers including assert.h (I had the same problem using the assimp library and ImageMagick) but I don't get why the order matters.

Reproducing your case, assert.h is included in:

- cassert for boost
- MagickCore/pixel-accessor.h for Magick++.h

If someone has an explanation for this problem feel free to edit.